# Find mongodb document by _id nodejs mongodb native

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find a document in a collection by its mongo "_id"

I am trying the following and not getting any result:

```
var collection = db.get('roadlist');
// Create a new ObjectID
var objectId = ObjectId(req.body._id);
collection.find(
    {
        "_id": objectId
    },
    {
    },
    function(e,docs) {
        console.log(e);
        res.json(docs);
});
```

Although I am getting a result by doing mongo shell find operation. I couldn’t find any solution in the previous similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixed up about the parameters the find method takes. It does not appear to take a callback directly, but has, instead, a toArray() method that accepts the callback:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find

So to get a result, do something like this:

```
collection.find(
    {"_id": objectId}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
       console.log(e);
        res.json(docs);
    });
```